# Duplicate result when using mysql join query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables as follows
   1) Tag_master

```
  id        tag_name
------------------------------
  1         Movies
  2         English Movies
```

2) Tags

```
   Tag_id          article
----------------------------------
     1               ABC
     2               ABC
     1               XYZ
     1               PQR
     2               EFG
     1               EFG
     2               LMN
     2               HIJ 
 --------------------------------
```

3)article_view

```
     article          view_date
  --------------------------------
       ABC            2015-07-01
       ABC            2015-07-01
       ABC            2015-07-02
       ABC            2015-07-03
       XYZ            2015-07-05
       XYZ            2015-07-05
       XYZ            2015-07-08
       PQR            2015-08-01
       PQR            2015-08-01
       LMN            2015-08-02
       HIJ            2015-08-02
 -----------------------------------
```

I want to get no of viewers for each article those 'Tag' containing word **Movies**

My query as follow

```
 select t.article,count(*) as cnt from tags t LEFT JOIN tag_master tm ON  
  t.tag_id=tm.id INNER JOIN article_view act ON t.article=act.article  
 WHERE tm.tag_name LIKE '%movies%' group by article
```

it give the following result

```
  article   cnt
 ----------------   
   ABC       8
   HIJ       1
   LMN       1
   PQR       2
   XYZ       3    
-----------------
```

In this result article **ABC** have only 4 viewers but in query result it showing 8

please help me to correct the query

Comment: Be careful what you count. Also, you have no PK on article_views. This may prove problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comment `Be careful what you count` so you need to get the count from `article_view` separately and then join back something as

```
select 
 t.article,
 act.cnt 
 from tags t 
 LEFT JOIN tag_master tm ON  t.tag_id=tm.id 
 INNER JOIN (
   select count(*) as cnt, article from article_view
   group by article
 )act
 ON t.article=act.article  
 WHERE 
 tm.tag_name LIKE '%movies%' 
 group by article
```

Comment: Well, not really. Properly, you need a PK on article_views, and then a COUNT of DISTINCT values returned from that table.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you query from article_view table

```
select article,count(view_date) as cnt from article_view group by article
```

??

> you should count **view_date** in your query

Comment: i need to connect with **tag_master** because when ever another tag came your query not suit for this

Comment: that ok.. Did you try count(t.view_date) in your query

Comment: Also you can user inner join instead of left join